# How to send NULL value in date field using mongoose and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am creating a user management module using express.js in which I have a field 'UserLastAccess' as Date in schema UserLastAccess: { type: Date}  and calling Users.save() in post method.

I am unable to send null value in the above mentioned field using postman. I have tried so far "UserLastAcces": null, [], '' using body but nothing works. That field will have a date once user will be authenticated so thats why upon creation of User it has to go null.

Comment: You can skip that field altogether in the post request. Because I think you will be using `new Date()` in your logic when you set the date-time for that field.

Comment: Nayan, I am not setting new Date(). I think i cannot send null into a date field once its defined as type Date.

Comment: You can try `default: undefined` with the field  if that works for you.

Comment: will try and to set date time format is there anyrhing builtin or ppl use libraries?

Comment: Explore `moment` very famous for handling date in JavaScript

Comment: Should I do like UserLastAccess: { type: Date  default: undefined } ??

Comment: Yes i guess you missed a , just after Date

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212904/discussion-between-nayan-and-user342944).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few possible solutions are

- Don't send the field in the post request and it will be ignored or set to any default defined in the schema
- You can also set the `default` for the field as `undefined` so there will be no value initially